# Selenium RC - Firefox browser does not launch

Tags: firefox, selenium-rc, launch

I had a problem in tools.jar so I downloaded jdk and changed the environmental variables.

Now I have the HUB and RC listening.

But when I run the test script , it is unable to launch Firefox

I tired to uninstall and install Firefox 3.6 again, then created new profile for Firefox

I went to  selenium-server.jar Unzip it, find all (of 5) “install.rdf” files inside this JAR (they are under customProfileDirCUSTFF and customProfileDirCUSTFFCHROME subfolders).

```
Changed the line from this <em:maxVersion>3.5.*</em:maxVersion> to this <em:maxVersion>3.6.*</em:maxVersion>
```

But still Firefox browser is not launched.
Please help.

Following is the error message:

```
C:\selenium\launch>title RC5560

C:\selenium\launch>cd C:\selenium\Grid\selenium-grid-1.0.4

C:\selenium\Grid\selenium-grid-1.0.4>C:\ant\bin\ant -DseleniumArgs="-firefoxProf
ileTemplate C:\Firefoxprofile -userExtensions 'C:\selenium\abilityplayer\Seleniu
m Extension scripts\CORE Extension\user-extensions.js'" -Denvironment="*firefox"
 -Dport=5560 launch-remote-control
Buildfile: build.xml

launch-remote-control:
     [java] jan 23, 2013 9:58:16 AM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.remotecontrol
.RegistrationRequest execute
     [java] INFO: Registering to http://localhost:4444/registration-manager/regi
ster
     [java] jan 23, 2013 9:58:16 AM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.remotecontrol
.SelfRegisteringRemoteControl launch
     [java] INFO: Starting selenium server with options:
     [java] jan 23, 2013 9:58:16 AM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.remotecontrol
.SelfRegisteringRemoteControl launch
     [java] INFO: -firefoxProfileTemplate
     [java] jan 23, 2013 9:58:16 AM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.remotecontrol
.SelfRegisteringRemoteControl launch
     [java] INFO: C:\Firefoxprofile
     [java] jan 23, 2013 9:58:16 AM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.remotecontrol
.SelfRegisteringRemoteControl launch
     [java] INFO: -userExtensions
     [java] jan 23, 2013 9:58:16 AM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.remotecontrol
.SelfRegisteringRemoteControl launch
     [java] INFO: C:\selenium\abilityplayer\Selenium Extension scripts\CORE Exte
nsion\user-extensions.js
     [java] jan 23, 2013 9:58:16 AM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.remotecontrol
.SelfRegisteringRemoteControl launch
     [java] INFO: -port
     [java] jan 23, 2013 9:58:16 AM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.remotecontrol
.SelfRegisteringRemoteControl launch
     [java] INFO: 5560
     [java] 09:58:16.543 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 23.6-b04
     [java] 09:58:16.543 INFO - OS: Windows XP 5.1 x86
     [java] 09:58:16.543 INFO - v1.0.1 [2696], with Core v@VERSION@ [@REVISION@]

     [java] 09:58:16.652 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
     [java] 09:58:16.652 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/sel
enium-server/driver]
     [java] 09:58:16.652 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-s
erver]
     [java] 09:58:16.652 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
     [java] 09:58:16.652 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:5560
     [java] 09:58:16.652 INFO - Started org.mortbay.jetty.Server@1eae15f
     [java] 09:58:29.118 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
     [java] 09:58:29.118 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
     [java] 09:58:29.118 INFO - Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*firefox,
http://ondemand.shl.com/] on session null
     [java] 09:58:29.134 INFO - creating new remote session
     [java] 09:58:29.321 INFO - Allocated session 3c67617374474d1c98f449a724ecb9
68 for http://ondemand.shl.com/, launching...
     [java] 09:58:31.024 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
     [java] 09:58:54.035 ERROR - Failed to start new browser session, shutdown b
rowser and clear all session data
     [java] java.lang.RuntimeException: Firefox refused shutdown while preparing
 a profile
     [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLaun
cher.waitForFullProfileToBeCreated(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:311)
     [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLaun
cher.populateCustomProfileDirectory(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:106)
     [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLaun
cher.launch(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:83)
     [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLaun
cher.launchRemoteSession(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:350)
     [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxLauncher.l
aunchRemoteSession(FirefoxLauncher.java:98)
     [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.createNewRem
oteSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:357)
     [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowse
rSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:122)
     [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowse
rSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:84)
     [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.getN
ewBrowserSession(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:699)
     [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.doCo
mmand(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:393)
     [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.hand
leCommandRequest(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:364)
     [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.hand
le(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:125)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:8
20)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.jav
a:986)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:83
7)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListen
er.java:245)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:35
7)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:53
4)
     [java] Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChrome
Launcher$FileLockRemainedException: Lock file still present! C:\DOCUME~1\ARTPUS~
1\LOCALS~1\Temp\customProfileDir3c67617374474d1c98f449a724ecb968\parent.lock
     [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLaun
cher.waitForFileLockToGoAway(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:269)
     [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLaun
cher.waitForFullProfileToBeCreated(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:309)
     [java]     ... 20 more
```

When firefox prepares to launch a folder is created (say) `C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Local Settings\Temp\customProfileDird47599b65f3246a9b14e72e6d7fdda84`

A Parent.lock file is created . This may be preventing Firefox to launch.

Comment: The Parent.lock file is to ensure that , no other instance of firefox runs using the same profile. And in selenuim, a temporary profile is created for every instance you launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing the change mentioned in the below link

http://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/creating-firefox-profile-for-your-selenium-rc-tests/

solved my problem